# UDP Server and public IP

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm trying to build a UDP client and server in C# which will communicate over the internet.
I used UdpClient like this:

```
    IPAddress publicIp = IPAddress.Any;
    IPEndPoint boundPort = new IPEndPoint(publicIp, 11110);
    m_udp = new UdpClient(boundPort);
```

In the server.

In the client I tried sending packets to that port with my public IP (which I got from the website:
 https://www.whatismyip.com

But my server doesn't get this packets...
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you behind a NAT?

Comment: Yes, I guess I am... I'm using a wireless router.

Comment: So you should redirect that port to your computer IP in the router configuration.